# aos.css is not working on django back end website

Tags: css, django, aos.js

I have a django back end website and I tried to load the css in HTML as follows.

```
{% load static %}
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/aos.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

however this makes all texts on my website completely transparent. I can still see the letter is there by cursoring tho.
I tried to not add aos.css but with bootstrap.min.css and index.css and they worked fine.
Is aos.css not compatible with django framework?

Answer (score 0):

Django is a backend framework so you don't have to worry about it's comparability since you're integrating aos on frontend. Did you load up the aos.js? An alternative would be to use the CDN.

Comment: How do you load up aos.js?